# Unable to push to existing heroku app

Tags: git, heroku

So I have this app in my heroku and I want to push my code into it. 
I did a `heroku git:remote -a harjutus2`    and it tells me `Git remote heroku allready exist`. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This nice article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) explains the basics of git for `heroku`.

To push, first you have to `commit`.

try:

```
git commit -am "1st"
git remote add heroku
git push  heroku master
```

these are different commands. Try running them one after another.

Comment: The git remote add heroku gives me the manual output every time I use it. I then try to follow the guide of the manual and it still wont go thorugh. What am I using wrong with that command..

Comment: and what is the output of `git push heroku master`?

Comment: That it is trying to push into a remote repository which does not exist anymore. But I want it to go into harjutus2. And thats what I wanted to change in the first place :D

Answer (score 0):

After updating your git branch like this:

- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Insert Any Description you choose"`
- `git push origin your-branch-name`

Do this to update already existing heroku with the new code changes:

- `git push heroku your-branch-name:master`

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue

- git commit -m "My first commit" # Creates initial commit
- heroku create # To create a new app

#If you want to push code to already created app

- heroku git:remote -a tranquil-hamlet-92495(Mention the Full name of
  the app created in Heroku)
- git push heroku master

This will solve the issue